# Android app crash after switching fragments

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

my app is going to crash when i switch fragments. I have main fragment with chat. When i switching fragments with bottomNavigationBar and coming back to main chat fragment my app is going to crash

```
    Process: com.example.uwebeta1, PID: 11210
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Application android.app.Activity.getApplication()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.checkApplication(ViewModelProviders.java:42)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(ViewModelProviders.java:122)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(ViewModelProviders.java:85)
        at com.example.uwebeta1.Adapter.ChatAdapter.<init>(ChatAdapter.java:68)
        at com.example.uwebeta1.Views.Fragments.MainActivityFragments.MainMasterFragment$9.onSuccessCallback(MainMasterFragment.java:366)
        at com.example.uwebeta1.Views.Fragments.MainActivityFragments.MainMasterFragment$9.onSuccessCallback(MainMasterFragment.java:362)
        at com.example.uwebeta1.Repository.ChatsRepository$1.onDataChange(ChatsRepository.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11210 SIG: 9
Process 11210 terminated.
```

This is my adapter class

```
  public ChatAdapter(Context mContext, List<ChatModel> mChat, String activityName, String city) {
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.activityName = activityName;
        this.city = city;

        userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) mContext).get(UserViewModel.class);
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    }
```

Here is my method were i getting data for adapter class

```
chatsViewModel.getMainChatByRoom(cityName, activityName, new MyFirebaseCallBack<List<ChatModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccessCallback(List<ChatModel> object) {

                            chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getContext(), object, activityName, cityName);
                            recycler_view.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailureCallback(String message) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you pass a reference to a `Fragment` into the repository via the anonymous `MyFirebaseCallBack`. If `onDataChange()` in the repository fires, `MyFirebaseCallback.onSuccessCallback()` is invoked. Since the `Fragment`instance for which the following line is executed

```
chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getContext(), object, activityName, cityName);
```

is no longer attached to any `Activity`, its `getContext()` returns `null`.

With the [(anti-)pattern](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) of passing a callback into a `ViewModel` method, it's up to you to check if `getContext()` returns `null`. If it does, you should not modify anything related to `View`s. Please note also that the detached `Fragment` instance may never again be attached to an `Activity`.

Instead, you can take advantage of the fact that a `ViewModel` is lifecycle-aware.
Let `getMainChatByRoom(cityName, activityName)` return a `LiveData<List<ChatModel>>` and register an `Observer<List<ChatModel>>` in `Fragment.onActivityCreated()` like this:

```
chatsViewModel.getMainChatByRoom(cityName, activityName).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<ChatModel>>(){
    @Override
    onChange(@Nullable List<ChatModel> data){
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getContext(), object, activityName, cityName);
        recycler_view.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    }
}
```

(Android Studio is likely to exchange most of that for a lambda expression but I wanted to show you how the `Observer` is set up)

See also the guides an android app architecture, especially [Observe LiveData objects](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects)